# Есть ли смысл использовать SVG для такого случая

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Только учусь писать на Django. Хочу сделать веб-приложение по выбору инженерного оборудования. При выборе из выпадающего списка хочу чтобы изменялась не вся схема, а только тот модуль, который изменен. Вариантов для каждого модуля много.

Думаю, можно ли нарисовать схему в SVG и уже ее менять как модуль? Подскажите как решаете такой вопрос? Поделитесь опытом, пожалуйста.

Например, для данной схемы меняю для модулей Т11 и Т21 характеристику и хочу поменять только их.
**Исходное значение:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**Значение после изменения характеристики:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем заранее спасибо!

Пример получившегося SVG

```js
$('#scheme .module').each(function(i, m) {
  let moduleId = m.id;

  $('.option', m).each((optionNo) => {
    let but = document.createElement('button');
    $(but)
      .data('module', moduleId)
      .data('option', optionNo)
      .text(moduleId + ' type ' + optionNo);

    $('#controls').append(but);
  })
  $('#controls').append('<br>');
});

$('#controls button').click(function() {
  let moduleId = $(this).data('module');
  let optionNo = $(this).data('option');

  $('#' + moduleId + ' .option').fadeOut();
  $('#' + moduleId + ' .option').eq(optionNo).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#scheme {
  float: left;
}

#scheme .module .option~.option {
  display: none;
}

#controls {
  margin-left: 350px;
}

#controls button {
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="scheme" width="800" height="500" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 211.67 132.29" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <title>sheme</title>
 <path d="m158.69 122.23v-55.869h1v55.869z" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".17556" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 <path d="m161.19 66.362a2 2 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2 2z" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".53" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 <g fill="#ff00bf">
  <path d="m146.69 122.36v-106h1v106z" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".24181" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <path d="m149.19 61.362a2 2 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2 2z" stroke-width=".53" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <path d="m136.49 60.862h10.742v1h-10.742z" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".076977" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 </g>
 <path d="m44.958 19.626h123.47v99.472h-123.47z" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="2.11122, 0.527804" stroke-width=".5278" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 <path d="m136.54 65.862h22.705v1h-22.705z" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".11192" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 <path d="m111.06 53.767h25.19v25.19h-25.19z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" stroke-dasharray="0.810003, 0.810003" stroke-width=".81" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 <g>
  <g fill="#f00">
   <circle cx="79.194" cy="61.362" r="2" stroke-width=".53" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-122.36" y="78.694" width="106" height="1" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".24181" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="78.694" y="60.862" width="31.966" height="1" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".13279" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-122.36" y="66.694" width="106" height="1" fill="#cd2027" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".24181" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-122.36" y="54.694" width="106" height="1" fill="#00f" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".24181" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <rect x="67.194" y="65.862" width="43.467" height="1" fill="#cd2027" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".15485" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <circle cx="67.194" cy="66.362" r="2" fill="#cd2027" stroke-width=".53" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <g fill="#00f">
   <rect x="55.194" y="70.862" width="55.45" height="1" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".1749" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <circle cx="55.194" cy="71.362" r="2" stroke-width=".53" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="34.694" y="119.36" width="144" height=".2" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".12605" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="34.694" y="19.362" width="144" height=".2" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".12605" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
  <g fill="#007fff" stroke="#000">
   <rect x="167.71" y="119.56" width="10.982" height="2.8" stroke-width=".037135" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="86.914" y="119.59" width="53.198" height="2.7413" stroke-width=".080871" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="34.703" y="119.57" width="9.8937" height="2.7704" stroke-width=".098276" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="168.43" y="16.562" width="10.264" height="2.8" stroke-width=".07588" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="86.914" y="16.6" width="53.231" height="2.7683" stroke-width=".081293" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="34.698" y="16.566" width="10.267" height="2.7768" stroke-width=".086918" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
  <g stroke="#000">
   <rect x="180.74" y="75.064" width="24.968" height=".11794" stroke-width=".032058" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="matrix(.84826 -.52958 .88472 .46612 0 0)" x="-5.0388" y="184.69" width="25.397" height=".10442" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".085398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="matrix(.9618 -.27376 .97234 .23356 0 0)" x="-97.88" y="248.19" width="34.664" height=".14704" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".11839" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="11.079" y="50.606" width="24.968" height=".11794" stroke-width=".032058" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="matrix(-.92463 -.38087 .89866 -.43865 0 0)" x="-103.11" y="-44.467" width="21.078" height=".078484" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".093078" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="matrix(-.99024 -.13936 .98638 -.16449 0 0)" x="-230.08" y="-150.67" width="43.752" height=".15896" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".19084" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="10.926" y="106.01" width="24.968" height=".11794" stroke-width=".032058" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="matrix(.98184 .18973 -.97477 .22321 0 0)" x="275.83" y="241.01" width="32.136" height=".11714" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".14041" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
  <g fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="8.4667px" stroke-width=".26458">
   <text x="182.54907" y="72.303764" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="182.54907" y="72.303764" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" stroke-width=".26458">Ду20</tspan></text>
   <text x="12.546672" y="48.452499" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="12.546672" y="48.452499" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" stroke-width=".26458">Ду32</tspan></text>
   <text x="12.546672" y="102.72215" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="12.546672" y="102.72215" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" stroke-width=".26458">Ду25</tspan></text>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="modules">
    <g id="t21" class="module">
<g id="T21_V" class="option" fill="#007fff">
  <path transform="matrix(.11085 0 0 .12679 154.49 14.686)" d="m144.36 276.58 37.115-61.904 35.053 63.095-36.084-0.59545z" stroke-width="1.0016" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <path transform="matrix(.11085 0 0 .12679 154.44 31.963)" d="m144.36 276.58 37.115-61.904 35.053 63.095-36.084-0.59545z" stroke-width="1.0016" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.008" y="174.04" width="37.225" height="1" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".1433" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <path transform="matrix(-.11085 0 0 -.12679 194.67 86.402)" d="m144.36 276.58 37.115-61.904 35.053 63.095-36.084-0.59545z" stroke-width="1.0016" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <path transform="matrix(.13857 0 0 .15849 149.38 36.03)" d="m144.36 276.58 37.115-61.904 35.053 63.095-36.084-0.59545z" stroke-width="1.0016" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_P" class="option" fill="#007fff">
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="50.062" height="1" opacity=".8806" stroke-width=".16618" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <path transform="matrix(.13857 0 0 .15849 149.38 36.03)" d="m144.36 276.58 37.115-61.904 35.053 63.095-36.084-0.59545z" stroke-width="1.0016" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_Т" class="option">
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="50.062" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".16618" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_KNv" class="option">
  <g transform="translate(-19.447 -12.237)">
   <desc>Неподвижная опора</desc>
   <title>NOpora</title>
   <rect transform="rotate(228.09)" x="-172.88" y="108.61" width="8" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".066431" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-41.914)" x="105.11" y="168.38" width="8" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".066431" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(-28.459 4.3306)" fill="#007fff" stroke="#007fff">
   <rect x="200.02" y="62.814" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="200.02" y="47.44" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-50.385" y="202.52" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-62.803" y="202.5" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <g stroke-width=".026529">
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="95.732" y="183.62" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-187.24" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-190.87" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="90.974" y="190.88" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="92.109" y="190.87" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="18.958" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".10226" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-51.807" y="174.03" width="14.807" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".090379" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_KNn" class="option">
  <g transform="translate(-28.459 4.3306)" fill="#007fff" stroke="#007fff">
   <rect x="200.02" y="62.814" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="200.02" y="47.44" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-50.385" y="202.52" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-62.803" y="202.5" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <g stroke-width=".026529">
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="95.732" y="183.62" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-187.24" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-190.87" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="90.974" y="190.88" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="92.109" y="190.87" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="18.958" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".10226" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-51.807" y="174.03" width="14.807" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".090379" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <g transform="translate(-28.459 4.3306)" fill="#007fff" stroke="#007fff">
   <rect x="200.02" y="62.814" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect x="200.02" y="47.44" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-50.385" y="202.52" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-62.803" y="202.5" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <g stroke-width=".026529">
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="95.732" y="183.62" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-187.24" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-190.87" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="90.974" y="190.88" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="92.109" y="190.87" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   </g>
  </g>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="18.958" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".10226" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-51.807" y="174.03" width="14.807" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".090379" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <g transform="translate(-19.535 87.063)">
   <desc>Неподвижная опора</desc>
   <title>NOpora</title>
   <rect transform="rotate(228.09)" x="-172.88" y="108.61" width="8" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".066431" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-41.914)" x="105.11" y="168.38" width="8" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".066431" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_Nn" class="option">
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="50.062" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".16618" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_Nv" class="option">
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="50.062" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".16618" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  <g id="NOpora" transform="translate(-19.447 -12.237)">
   <desc>Неподвижная опора</desc>
   <title>NOpora</title>
   <rect transform="rotate(228.09)" x="-172.88" y="108.61" width="8" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".066431" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
   <rect transform="rotate(-41.914)" x="105.11" y="168.38" width="8" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".066431" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="T21_K" class="option">
  <g id="t21_K_komp" transform="translate(-28.459 4.3306)">
   <title>t21_K_komp</title>
   <g fill="#007fff" stroke="#007fff">
    <rect x="200.02" y="62.814" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect x="200.02" y="47.44" width="5.966" height=".96602" stroke-width=".03398" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-50.385" y="202.52" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-62.803" y="202.5" width="1.9804" height=".96953" stroke-width=".019613" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    <g stroke-width=".026529">
     <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="95.732" y="183.62" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
     <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-187.24" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
     <rect transform="rotate(222.2)" x="-190.87" y="94.762" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
     <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="90.974" y="190.88" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
     <rect transform="rotate(-47.801)" x="92.109" y="190.87" width="3.6233" height=".96953" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers"/>
    </g>
   </g>
  </g>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-87.062" y="174.04" width="18.958" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".10226" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers">
   <title>t21_K_pipe2</title>
  </rect>
  <rect transform="rotate(-90)" x="-51.807" y="174.03" width="14.807" height="1" fill="#007fff" stroke-width=".090379" style="paint-order:stroke fill markers">
   <title>t21_K_pipe1</title>
  </rect>
 </g>
 <g id="Marks" display="none" fill="#000000" font-family="sans-serif" stroke-width=".26458">
  <g font-size="8.4667px">
   <text transform="rotate(-90)" x="-137.79126" y="177.83511" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-137.79126" y="177.83511" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">T21</tspan></text>
   <text transform="rotate(-90)" x="-124.02296" y="164.9431" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-124.02296" y="164.9431" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">T11</tspan></text>
   <text x="128.82991" y="70.750648" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="128.82991" y="70.750648" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">S1(1)</tspan></text>
   <text transform="rotate(-90)" x="-121.87818" y="96.919701" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-121.87818" y="96.919701" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">T3</tspan></text>
   <text transform="rotate(-90)" x="-130.84679" y="85.489937" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-130.84679" y="85.489937" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">T4</tspan></text>
   <text transform="rotate(-90)" x="-123.27343" y="73.220779" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-123.27343" y="73.220779" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-size="8.4667px" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458">В1</tspan></text>
  </g>
  <text transform="rotate(-90)" x="-123.27343" y="43.710255" font-size="10.583px" style="line-height:1.25" xml:space="preserve"><tspan x="-123.27343" y="43.710255" font-family="'Times New Roman'" font-weight="bold" stroke-width=".26458"/></text>
 </g>
    </g>
 </g>

</svg>
<div id="controls"></div>
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, это наилучший подход. Вы можете использовать любой векторный графический редактор для подготовки схем и вариантов конфигурации. Затем при помощи JS на сайте отображаете нужные компоненты. Т.е. Вам достаточно будет нарисовать одну схему со всеми модулями и их вариантами, один файл SVG, а на сайте показываете только элементы требуемой конфигурации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Это должна быть одна схема со всеми модулями, а скриптом я просто отключаю видимость все не нужные? Или я должен создать все модули и уже их подгружать в итоговую схему?

Comment: Да, скорее всего, я так бы и делал. Весь цикл подготовки, публикации и взаимодействия со схемой понятен. Всё уже на своих местах, только видимость задавай. На счет подгружать, думаю, это зависит от размера схемы, количества модулей и вариаций. Если элементов там не тысячи, то нет смысла.

Comment: Варианта три: 1. Вы извращенец и пишите всё это на HTML; 2. Вы умный и делаете это на canvas; 3. Вы хитрый и делаете это на SVG. Лично я вижу следующих плюс от SVG, что оно как и HTML имеет возможность прятать\показывать свои элементы\слои, тем самым вы можете создать один элемент SVG, в котором будут все возможные варианты, которые просто будете вкл\выкл, в зависимости от выбранного модуля

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я набросал пример, чтобы продемонстрировать как это может выглядеть. Схему нарисовал в Corel, неизменяемая часть в одном слое, модули с вариантами сгруппированы в отдельном слое. Ну а дальше забавляемся с опциями:

```js
$('#scheme .module').each(function(i, m) {
  let moduleId = m.id;

  $('.option', m).each((optionNo) => {
    let but = document.createElement('button');
    $(but)
      .data('module', moduleId)
      .data('option', optionNo)
      .text(moduleId + ' type ' + optionNo);

    $('#controls').append(but);
  })
  $('#controls').append('<br>');
});

$('#controls button').click(function() {
  let moduleId = $(this).data('module');
  let optionNo = $(this).data('option');

  $('#' + moduleId + ' .option').fadeOut();
  $('#' + moduleId + ' .option').eq(optionNo).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
#scheme {
  float: left;
}

#scheme .module .option~.option {
  display: none;
}

#controls {
  margin-left: 350px;
}

#controls button {
  margin: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="scheme" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="328" height="341" viewBox="0 0 111.718 116.145">
  <defs>
    <style>.str4,.str5{stroke:#000;stroke-width:.257463}.str4{stroke-width:1.02174}.str0,.str1,.str2,.str3{stroke:#00f;stroke-width:1.02174}.str1,.str2,.str3{stroke:#69f}.str1,.str3{stroke:red}.str3{stroke:#f0f}.fil0{fill:none}.fil1{fill:#000}.fil6{fill:#69f}.fil4{fill:#f0f;fill-rule:nonzero}.fnt0{font-weight:400;font-size:8px;font-family:Arial;}</style>
  </defs>
  <g id="fixed">
    <path class="fil0 str0" d="M8.85 8.856v107.289"/>
    <path class="fil0 str1" d="M17.365 8.856v107.289M25.88 8.856v107.289"/>
    <path class="fil0 str2" d="M102.515 8.856v107.289"/>
    <path class="fil0 str3" d="M94 8.856v107.289"/>
    <path class="fil0 str4" d="M.511.511h110.696v110.525H.511z"/>
    <path class="fil0 str3" d="M68.455 51.431H94"/>
    <path class="fil0 str2" d="M68.455 59.776h34.06"/>
    <path class="fil0 str1" d="M25.88 51.029h17.03M17.365 58.182H42.91"/>
    <path class="fil0 str0" d="M8.849 65.335H42.91"/>
    <text x="164" y="-47.344" class="fil1 fnt0" transform="rotate(-90 194.997 50.715)">T11</text>
    <text x="164" y="-47.344" class="fil1 fnt0" transform="rotate(-90 206.492 53.696)">T21</text>
    <path class="str4" style="fill:#fff" d="M42.91 42.916h25.545v25.545H42.91z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="modules">
    <g id="t11" class="module">
      <g id="t11-1" class="option">
        <path class="str5" style="fill:#fcc" d="M91.896 20.407h4.208v12.152h-4.208z"/>
        <path class="fil0 str4" d="m92.474 13.089 3.405 3.406"/>
        <path class="fil0 str4" d="m92.474 16.495 3.405-3.406"/>
      </g>
      <g id="t11-2" class="option">
        <path class="fil4" d="M96.409 13.673h-4.817L94 8.856l2.409 4.817zM95.205 11.264"/>
        <path class="fil4" d="M96.409 18.49h-4.817L94 13.673l2.409 4.817zM95.205 16.08"/>
        <path class="fil4" d="M96.409 23.307h-4.817L94 18.49l2.409 4.817zM95.205 20.898"/>
        <path class="fil4" d="M96.409 28.124h-4.817L94 23.307l2.409 4.817zM95.205 25.715"/>
        <path class="fil4" d="M96.409 32.94h-4.817L94 28.125l2.409 4.817zM95.205 30.533"/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="t21" class="module">
      <path id="t21-1" class="option str5" d="m100.818 32.528 3.393-14.767h-3.393l3.393 14.767h-3.393zM102.515 32.528" style="fill:#ff0;fill-rule:nonzero"/>
      <g id="t21-2" class="option">
        <circle class="fil6" cx="102.515" cy="11.264" r="2.555"/>
        <circle class="fil6" cx="102.515" cy="16.373" r="2.555"/>
        <circle class="fil6" cx="102.515" cy="21.483" r="2.555"/>
        <circle class="fil6" cx="102.515" cy="26.592" r="2.555"/>
        <circle class="fil6" cx="102.515" cy="31.701" r="2.555"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>

<div id="controls"></div>
```

P.S. Я совершенно не ведаю, что нарисовал ;)

Comment: Круто!!! Я примерно такое и хочу. Вот только разбираюсь в вопросе. Писал приложение для Autocad на VBA, а теперь хочу попробовать свои силы в Django и веб-ресурсами потому как нравится больше. Ты каждый вариант элемента в отдельный слой убирал? Только так его можно скрыть?

Comment: Каждый модуль является группой с классом `.module`. Каждая опция внутри является также группой с классом `.option`. Внутри уже геометрия. В SVG нет такого понятия "слой", всё преобразуется в группы. [Вот так](https://imgur.com/a/R7pHiM9) это выглядит у меня в Corel.

Comment: А в CSS я просто добавил правило `#scheme .module .option~.option`, которое в каждом модуле скрывает все опции, кроме первой.

Comment: Повторил твое решение, но немогу понять в чем причина. По всей видимости вопрос в JS.

Comment: Проверил, всё работает, прокрутите вниз, там кнопки, опции переключаются. SVG-документ большой 1920x1080px. При экспорте лучше ставить галку "только выделенные".

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое за помощь! Немного разобрался! 
Посоветую ресурс какой-нибудь для изучения JS. Если не сложно!

Comment: Это сложно, я плохо знаком с современными курсами/учебниками. Попробуйте [этот](https://learn.javascript.ru/) и [этот](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript). Кстати, в своем решении я использовал библиотеку jQuery.